# Error Developing a Class to Work With Tester

Tags: java

I was provided a tester (of which the code I cannot change) and I need to develop a class that works with this tester. I am having a hard time with my class. It seems as if I am getting an error "Cannot find symbol" error. It seems that I am building my methods wrong. I am new with Java and programming in general and would appreciate any help. This is my first stab at understanding object oriented programming.

Here is the Class:

```
package something;
import java.util.Random;

public class Drunkard 
{    
//field declaration  
public int startAvenue; 
public int Startstreet;
public Random r = new Random();

//constructors to initialize the instance variables
public Drunkard(int avenue, int street) 
{
    startAvenue = avenue;
    startStreet = street;
}

//step method
public void step() 
{
    int nextMove = rand.nextInt(3);

    if(nextMove == 0)
      {
        moveAhead();
      }
    else if (nextMove == 1)
      {
        moveUturn();
      }
    else if (nextMove == 2)
      {
        moveLeft();
      }
    else
      {
        moveRight();
      }
}

//String get location method
public String getLocation()
{
    int startAvenue = parseInt("avenue");
    int startStreet = parseInt("street");
    printf("Location:  " + avenue + "," + street);
}

//fastForward method
public void fastForward(int steps)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < steps.length; i++)
    {
        step();
    }
}

//howFar method
public int howFar()
{
    int distance = Math.abs(startAvenue - avenue) + Math.abs(startStreet -street);
}

} //end class
```

Here is the tester class that cannot be changed:

```
import something.Drunkard;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter the starting avenue integer: ");
int avenue = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter the starting street integer: ");
int street = input.nextInt();

// make the Drunkard with initial position
Drunkard ozzy = new Drunkard(avenue, street);

// have him move 100 intersections
ozzy.fastForward(100);

// get his current location
String location = ozzy.getLocation();

// get distance from start
int distance = ozzy.howFar();

System.out.println("Current location: " + location);
System.out.println("That's " + distance + " blocks from start.");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice in this snippet:

```
public class Drunkard 
{    
    //field declaration  
    public int startAvenue; 
    public int Startstreet;
    public Random r = new Random();

    //constructors to initialize the instance variables
    public Drunkard(int avenue, int street) 
    {
        startAvenue = avenue;
        startStreet = street;
    }
...
}
```

You have a field `public int Startstreet;` declared near the top, but in your constructor, you assign `startStreet = street;`. You're capitalizing different letters in each of those statements, which explains why Java can't find the symbol `startStreet`.

That's all I found at a quick glance.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I also noticed that after I posted and changed it.

Answer (score 0):

First issue here is the Startstreet and startStreet not being spelled the same.

Also you define the random object as r here which isn't a good habit to use a single letter and then use rand in the step method so those don't match either.

```
public int startAvenue; 
public int Startstreet;
public Random r = new Random();

//constructors to initialize the instance variables
public Drunkard(int avenue, int street) 
{
    startAvenue = avenue;
    startStreet = street;
}
```

Next up, rand.nextInt(3) will chose a random number that is between 0 and less than 3 so 0, 1, or 2 so the final else block will never be run.

Change it to rand.nextInt(4) so that the else block actually has a chance to run.
I assume you haven't made the methods MoveAhead(), MoveUTurn(), MoveLeft() and MoveRight() yet as they aren't in the code so I won't comment on those.

A switch statement would be much cleaner instead of your current statements if you want to look that up but not neccesary.

```
//step method
public void step() 
{
    int nextMove = rand.nextInt(3);

    if(nextMove == 0)
      {
        moveAhead();
      }
    else if (nextMove == 1)
      {
        moveUturn();
      }
    else if (nextMove == 2)
      {
        moveLeft();
      }
    else
      {
        moveRight();
      }
}
```

This method is supposed to return a string and startAvenue and startStreet are already global values defined in the constructor. (printf is also being very misused here also)
You can remove all 3 lines and simply put

return ("Location: "+startAvenue+", "+startStreet);

```
public String getLocation()
{
    int startAvenue = parseInt("avenue");
    int startStreet = parseInt("street");
    printf("Location:  " + avenue + "," + street);
}
```

The variable steps is an integer and integers don't have a length. You want it to run for the number of steps just entered so remove the .length in the for loop.

```
public void fastForward(int steps)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < steps.length; i++)
    {
        step();
    }
}
```

Again your method is supposed to return an integer and you have no return statement anywhere. Also I assume a distance would be asking for the direct distance so using the formula a^2 + b^2 = c^2 I would write

```
public double howFar() {
return Math.sqrt( (Math.pow(startAvenue - avenue,2)) + (Math.pow(startAvenue - avenue,2)) );
}
```

rather than

```
public int howFar()
{
    int distance = Math.abs(startAvenue - avenue) + Math.abs(startStreet -street);
}
```

Comment: also you should really be using different variables for startAvenue and startStreet and currentAvenue and currentStreet because right now you're using them interchangeably when in actuality the currentAvenue and startAvenue won't be the same after the first move and in the howFar method you can't use avenue and street because they aren't defined anywhere in that method